# Running multiprocessing on imported functions. Python 3.11.5 - Windows - Pycharm

Tags: python, windows, import, multiprocessing

I am trying to create a simulation and I have a problem running the logic function with multiprocessing. After some debugging the problem seems to arise from the fact that multiprocessing runs the whole imported script again and again when I am using something imported from it, like an imported function. My actual code is a bit complex so I want to share this simple code where the same problem exists.

```
"""The test script I am running"""
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
import os
from plus import plus

def parallel():
    p1 = Process(target=plus)
    p1.start()

def main():
    print("test")
    while True:
        parallel()
        time.sleep(2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
"""The imported plus script"""
print('plus run')
def plus():
    print(2+3)
    return 2+3
```

the result is:

```
plus run
test
plus run
5
plus run
5
plus run
5
plus run
5
```

As you can see from the multiple plus run it seems like my imported script is being imported over and over! In the larger simulation this slows things down considerably.

Comment: python's multiprocessing sends the target function to the child process via `pickle` which does not actually serialize the function itself, but rather just how to import it for use in the child. The solution here is to make sure your child processes are long-lived enough to justify the overhead they incur starting up.

Comment: Is the question ultimately, why is *"plus run"* printed all the time?

Comment: The answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do but yes, essentially your second script is constantly being reimported. It is a reminder that you really want to avoid doing any unnecessary work outside of a `__name__ == "__main__"` guard.